# Handshakes in a party

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

Here's the question which I'm stuck with -

> There are $20$ married couples at a party. Every man shakes hands with everyone except himself and his spouse. Half of the women refuse to shake hands with any other women. The other $10$ women all shake hands with each other (but not with themselves). How many handshakes are there at the party?

**My Solution:**

1. *Handshakes done by men*: There are $20$ ways to pick a man and $38$ ways to pick the other person, totaling to $20 \cdot 38 = 760$. But since every handshake is counted twice, the answer is $\frac{760}{2} = 380$
2. *Handshakes done by the women who refuse to shake hand with any other women*: these are already counted in $380$ handshakes (Because the women can only shake hands with men. This was taken care of above).
3. *Handshakes done by the other $10$ women and men*: These are counted in $380$ handshakes.
4. *Handshakes done by women and women in the group of $10$*: are $\binom{10}{2} = 45$.

Hence the total handshakes are $380 + 45 = 425$.

---

However, the total handshakes are $615$ according to my textbook. Can anyone please help me to find out the mistake?

Comment: After you compute the number of handshakes done by each man, you divide by 2 because "every handshake is counted twice".  But, you also ignore handshakes between men and women because those are "already counted in [the] 380 handshakes".  This means you're miscounting something here -- you're missing a whole bunch of handshakes between men and women.  I recommend waiting until the very end to divide anything by 2.

Comment: There is a non-maths problem in here: this question is unanswerable unless you assume that each married couple consists of one man and one woman, which is no longer a valid assumption these days and is not stated in the question.

Comment: Good problem. While reading it, I did the exact same reason you did for some reason. Lol !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your mistake can be seen in your first line: you should not divide by $2$ as you did not count the handshakes between men and women twice.

Instead, the ways to pick a man is $20$. The number of men that shake hands with him is $19$. Since very handshake is counted twice, the men shake hands $190$ times.

The number of handshakes men had with women is simply $20 \times 19$, thus $380$.

Combining this with your results gives the answer in the textbook, or $570+45=615$.

Answer (score 3):

There are the following types of handshakes

1. Woman vs woman: $\dbinom{10}{2}=45$. You were correct on that.
2. Man vs man: $\dbinom{20}{2}=190$.
3. Man vs woman: each man performs $19$ handshakes with women. Since there are $20$ men this gives $$19\times20=380$$ such handshakes.

Summing up $$45+190+380=615$$ Your mistake was in steps $2$ and $3$ because you treated them as $1$ step. While handshakes between man and man are counted indeed twice, handshakes between man and woman are counted only once, so dividing all with $2$ is wrong. You have to distinguish between these two categories.