# Four married couples attend a party. Each person shakes hands with every other person, except their own spouse, exactly once. How many handshakes?

Tags: combinatorics

> Four married couples attend a party. Each person shakes hands with every other person, except their own spouse, exactly once. How many handshakes?

My book gave the answer as $24$. I do not understand why.

---

I thought of it like this:

You have four pairs of couples, so you can think of it as

M1W2, M2W2, M3W3, M4W4,

where
M is a man and W is a woman. M1 has to shake 6 other hands, excluding his wife. You have to do this 4 times for the other men, so you have $4\times 6$ handshakes, but in my answer, you are double counting.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: In your answer, you both overcounted and undercounted, and incidentally these happened to cancel out and give you the correct answer without having to do anything further. You did $4 \times (\text{Handshakes done by the men})$, which overcounted the man-man handshakes, but left out the woman-woman handshakes.

Comment: And that's easily fixed by counting all such handshakes in the same way, not just those done by men, so you get $48$. And _now_, as you said, you have indeed double-counted. But if you know it's exactly double counting, you can get the answer by halving it!

Comment: I recommend when you have a problem like this you can't solve, try solving an easier version first, like only 2 couples and anything goes.

Comment: Only person #1 has to shake hands 6 times, person #2 has already shaken hands with Person #1, so he only has to shake hands with 5 people. So the answer becomes 6+5+4+3+2+1, or 21. So Yes, I believe 21 is correct, to prevent double counting.

Comment: @Issel No, Person #2 being the spouse of Person #1, also has to shake hands with $6$ people, and so on, so it's $6 + 6 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 0 + 0 = 24$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handshakes in a party](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665187/handshakes-in-a-party)

Comment: @M.Vinay: You should have posted your comments as an answer, because even now all of the **eleven** existing answers have failed to explain the error in Zaku's attempt and how to fix it properly, unlike what you've done.

Comment: @user21820 Hm, if it gets reopened, I'll post an answer. I don't think I see why it got closed. Sure it's an elementary problem, but it clearly shows effort and at least a part of the question is why the specific method used seems to be wrong but gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 58):

$8$ people.  Each experiences   handshakes with $6$ people.  There are $6\times 8=48$ experiences of handshakes.  Each handshake is experienced by two people so there $48$ experiences means $48\div 2=24$ handshakes.

Answer (score 35):

Suppose the spouses were allowed to shake each other's hands. That would give you $\binom{8}{2} = 28$ handshakes. Since there are four couples, four of these handshakes are illegal. We can remove those to get the $24$ legal handshakes.

Comment: This uses Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Inclusion-Exclusion helps to find the cardinality of a union of non-disjoint sets. I'm merely using the fact that a set together with its complement (which are disjoint) comprise the entire universe.

Comment: and that's just a case of Inclusion-Exclusion Principle. (By the way, the set we're enumerating here isn't the 'entire universe', since it's not the total number of handshakes, or handshakes with all people in the world, or even n-way handshakes with all people.)

Answer (score 11):

You may proceed as follows using combinations:

- Number of all possible handshakes among 8 people: $\color{blue}{\binom{8}{2}}$
- Number of pairs who do not shake hands: $\color{blue}{4}$

It follows:
$$\mbox{number of hand shakes without pairs} = \color{blue}{\binom{8}{2}} - \color{blue}{4} = \frac{8\cdot 7}{2} - 4 = 24$$

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at it not from individuals, but from couples. There are four couples, i.e. $3!=6$ meetings of couples. Per meeting of couples, there are four handshakes. This makes it $6\times4=24$ handshakes.

---

Thanks @CJ Dennis for pointing out an error in the reasoning: It should, of course, be the sum, not the product, so the correct number of meetings of couples is
$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Each line is a handshake between the required two people.  There are 24 lines:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$k$ couples entails $2k$ people. If we imagine each couple going in sequential order, couple 1 will each have to shake $2k-2$ couple's hands for each individual, or $4k-4$ handshakes for couple 1 total.  Since there is 1 fewer couple every time a new couple shakes hands, there will be $4k-4i$ handshakes by the $i$-th couple. So the total number of handshakes is given by:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k (4k-4i) = \sum_{i=1}^k4k - \sum_{i=1}^k4i = 4k^2 - 4\frac{k(k+1)}{2} = 4(k^2 - \frac{k^2+k}{2}) = 4(k^2 - (\frac{k^2}{2} + \frac{k}{2})) = 4(\frac{k^2}{2}-\frac{k}{2}) = 2(k^2-k)$$

for $k$ couples. Plugging in $k$ = 4 verifies a solution of 24 for this case.

Comment: Well… Each of the $2k$ people shakes hands with $2k - 1 - 1 = 2k - 2$ others (everyone except the spouse). So that's $2k(2k- 2) = 4k(k - 1)$, but since every handshake must've been counted twice, divide that by $2$ to get $2k(k - 1)$ handshakes in total.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach:

There are 8 person in total.

Each one will shake hands with 6 others.

Total shakehands from individual perspective: 6*8 gives 48

Actual shakehands: 48/2 = 24

Comment: How is different from fleablood's answer?

Comment: @TobyMak sorry, I really didn't see it. When I posted there were only four answers including mine. That answer was really not there, completely surprised. I don't know how this happened?

Comment: I see. Since you wrote your answer independently from fleablood, it's only fair to  keep your answer.